# SQLAlchemy conversion of Django annotate

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I have the following annotation in a Django model manager I'd like to convert to a SQLAlchemy ORM query:

```
annotations = {
        'review_count' : Count("cookbookreview", distinct=True), 
        'rating' : Avg("cookbookreview__rating")
    }
return self.model.objects.annotate(**annotations)
```

What I essentially need is each model object in the query to have `review_count` and `rating` attached to them as part of the initial query. I believe I can use `column_property`, but I would like to avoid this type of "calculated property" on the object, because I don't want the property (expensive lookup) being done for each object when I access the property in a template.

What is the right way to approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, Django annotations and aggregations are pretty inconsistent hacks. SQLAlchemy is way more powerful than the Django ORM, basically you have the full power of SQL at your hands in reusable and parametric fashion.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem that Django ORM aggregate/annotate is solving here still needs to be solved in SQLAlchemy. Since it is quite powerful, I assume this type of query can be done with relative ease.. I haven't been able to figure out how, though.

Comment: You can map any sqlalchemy.sql.select using SqlSoup.

Comment: How does it work in Django if it's not a calculated property?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, for the sake of completeness and usefulness for others with this issue I present the following solution (which may or may not be the optimal way to solve this)

```
sq_reviews = db_session.query(CookbookReview.cookbook_id, 
    func.avg(CookbookReview.rating).label('rating'),\
    func.count('*').label('review_count')).\
    group_by(CookbookReview.cookbook_id).subquery()

object_list = db_session.query(
    Cookbook, sq_reviews.c.rating, sq_reviews.c.review_count).\
    outerjoin(sq_reviews, Cookbook.id==sq_reviews.c.cookbook_id).\
    order_by(Cookbook.name).limit(20)
```

The key here is the concept of [SQLAlchemy subqueries](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries). If you think of each annotation in my original Django query as a subquery, the concept is easier to understand. It's also worth noting that this query is quite speedy - many orders of magnitude swifter than it's (more concise/magical) Django counterpart. Hopefully this helps others curious about this particular Django/SQLAlchemy query analog.

Also keep in mind that you need to perform the actual annotation of the ORM objects yourself. A simple function like this called before sending the object list to your template will suffice:

```
def process(query):
    for obj, rating, review_count in query:
        obj.rating = rating
        obj.review_count = review_count
        yield obj
```

Comment: So you end up writing the template loop as `for record in process(query)`?

Comment: Subqueries can also be made with Django ORM... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions